# matplotlib histogram: how to display the count over the bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

With matplotlib's [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) function, how can one make it display the count for each bin over the bar?

For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [ ... ] # some data
plt.hist(data, bins=10)
```

How can we make the count in each bin display over its bar?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

it seems `hist` can't do this,you can write some like :

```
your_bins=20
data=[]
arr=plt.hist(data,bins=your_bins)
for i in range(your_bins):
    plt.text(arr[1][i],arr[0][i],str(arr[0][i]))
```

Answer (score 46):

#### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

There is a new [`plt.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) method to automatically label bar containers.

[`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) returns the bar container(s) as the third output:

```
data = np.random.default_rng(123).rayleigh(1, 70)
counts, edges, bars = plt.hist(data)
#              ^

plt.bar_label(bars)
```

[image]

If you have a grouped or stacked histogram, `bars` will contain multiple containers (one per group), so iterate:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
counts, edges, bars = ax.hist([data, data * 0.3], histtype='barstacked')

for b in bars:
    ax.bar_label(b)
```

[image]

Note that you can also access the bar container(s) via `ax.containers`:

```
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c)
```

Comment: Hello, what if there are some 0 values that I don't wanna display what I'm gonna do?

Comment: @Arkadian Pass a filtered list of `datavalues` using the `labels` param ([similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70516643/13138364)), e.g.: `plt.bar_label(bars, labels=[v if v > 0 else '' for v in bars.datavalues])`

Comment: How to apply this grouped histogram to list of df columns with one column determining group?

Comment: Why are you multiplying data by 0.3 in your example?

Comment: @Anscandance It's just random sample data to show stacking multiple datasets. One dataset is `data` and the other is `data*0.3`.

Answer (score 12):

Not solution solely using `plt.hist()` but with some added functionality.

If you don't want to specify your bins beforehand and only plot densities bars, but also want to display the bin counts you can use the following.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randn(100)
density, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, density=True, bins=20)
count, _ = np.histogram(data, bins)
for x,y,num in zip(bins, density, count):
    if num != 0:
        plt.text(x, y+0.05, num, fontsize=10, rotation=-90) # x,y,str
```

The result looks as follows:

[image]