# Adding Comma to Bar Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I have been using the `ax.bar_label` method to add data values to the bar graphs. The numbers are huge such as 143858918. How can I add commas to the data values using the `ax.bar_label` method? I do know how to add commas using the annotate method but if it is possible using `bar_label`, I am not sure. Is it possible using the `fmt` keyword argument that is available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible using the `fmt` keyword argument of [`ax.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html)?

Yes, but **only in matplotlib 3.7+**. Prior to 3.7, `fmt` only accepted `%` formatters (no comma support), so `labels` was needed to `f`-format the container's `datavalues`.

- If matplotlib ≥ 3.7, use `fmt`:

  ```
  for c in ax.containers:
      ax.bar_label(c, fmt='{:,.0f}')  # ≥ 3.7
      #                   ^no f here (not an actual f-string)
  ```
- If matplotlib < 3.7, use `labels`:

  ```
  for c in ax.containers:
      ax.bar_label(c, labels=[f'{x:,.0f}' for x in c.datavalues])  # < 3.7
  ```

---

Toy example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], [3200, 9025, 800])

# ≥ v3.7
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt='{:,.0f}')
```

```
# < v3.7
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=[f'{x:,.0f}' for x in c.datavalues])
```

[image]