# barplot labels to show full numbers instead of scientific formula

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm using [this kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/siddharthm1698/coursera-course-dataset) to perform my data analysis.
I converted `'course_students_enrolled'` column values to integers.
When I plot courses with highest numbers of students, I get a figure where bar labels that represent values above 1M appear written in formula like `1.3e+06` instead of showing the full number. Same goes with the number above the chart.
This is my code of the plot:

```py
popularity_filt = (main_df['course_students_enrolled'].sort_values(ascending=False))
most_pop_courses = main_df.iloc[popularity_filt.index][:10]
course_titles = most_pop_courses['title'].to_list()
data = most_pop_courses[['title','course_students_enrolled']]
sns.set_context(font_scale=3, rc={'font.size':12, 'axes.labelsize':20})
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
palette = sns.color_palette(palette="Greens_d", n_colors=len(data))
plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = sns.barplot(x='title', y='course_students_enrolled', data=data, palette=np.array(palette[::-1]));
ax.set_xticklabels(course_titles, rotation=40, ha='right')
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0]);

plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to show full numbers instead?

Comment: related: [how to format bar labels with comma separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70516643/13138364)

Comment: `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.0f')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it into the appropriate string using f-string:

```
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=[f'{x.get_height():.0f}' for x in ax.containers[0]])
```

Comment: There should be some syntax issue in your suggestion. I tried to change quotes and to put 'f' before quotes, but it's not working for me. Could you check if it's working as you wrote it?

Comment: I’ve changed place so that f is outside the quotes.

Comment: The quotes in your suggestion are not accepted by python.
And it's still not working after changing the quotes. This is qhat I get:
`TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Rectangle.__format__`

Comment: I’ve modified the answer.

Comment: once again, python does not accept that type of quotes. `"` or `'` needs to be used. Other than that, your suggestion works, but it does the contrary of what I was trying to achieve. Now all the numbers are shown in scientific formula format. :D
Anyway, I changed the `.1E` part to `.0f` and it worked fine (after quotes were changed to the type I indicated above).
Anyway, thanks A LOT for your effort to help.
If you can modify your answer to make sure that it has all the correct syntax, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Changed the quotation. Wonder if it is the phones keyboard that is screwing it up.

Comment: Could be. Anyway, those single quotes won't work either. Hopefully, this won't be too confusing for a newbie like me. :)

Comment: Directly setting the format seems to make more sense: `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.0f')`